# regex to remove certain characters at the beginning and end of a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

Let's say I have a string like this:

```
...hello world.bye
```

But I want to remove the first three dots and replace `.bye` with `!`

So the output should be

```
hello world!
```

it should only match if both conditions apply (`...` at the beginning and `.bye` at the end)

And I'm trying to use js replace method. Could you please help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First match the dots, capture and lazy-repeat any character until you get to `.bye`, and match the `.bye`. Then, you can replace with the first captured group, plus an exclamation mark:

```js
const str = '...hello world.bye';
console.log(str.replace(/\.\.\.(.*)\.bye/, '$1!'));
```

The lazy-repeat is there to ensure you don't match too much, for example:

```js
const str = `...hello world.bye
...Hello again! Goodbye.`;
console.log(str.replace(/\.\.\.(.*)\.bye/g, '$1!'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex would be

```js
const rx = /\.\.\.([\s\S]*?)\.bye/g

const out = '\n\nfoobar...hello world.bye\nfoobar...ok.bye\n...line\nbreak.bye\n'.replace(rx, `$1!`)

console.log(out)
```

In English, find three dots, anything eager in group, and ending with .bye.

The replacement uses the first match `$1` and concats `!` using a string template.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough in my question. this doesn't work for me because my string contains multiple lines and the match can happen anywhere inside the string, for example:

`blah blah blah
...first match.bye
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
blah blah blah ...second match.bye blah blah blah
blah blah blah`

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need a regex to do this. Although it's a bit inelegant, the following should work fine (obviously the function can be called whatever makes sense in the context of your application):

```
function manipulate(string) {
    if (string.slice(0, 3) == "..." && string.slice(-4) == ".bye") {
        return string.slice(4, -4) + "!";
    }
    return string;
}
```

(Apologies if I made any stupid errors with indexing there, but the basic idea should be obvious.)

This, to me at least, has the advantage of being easier to reason about than a regex. Of course if you need to deal with more complicated cases you may reach the point where a regex is best - but I personally wouldn't bother for a simple use-case like the one mentioned in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

An arguably simpler solution:

```
const str = '...hello world.bye'
const newStr = /...(.+)\.bye/.exec(str)

const formatted = newStr ? newStr[1] + '!' : str

console.log(formatted)
```

If the string doesn't match the regex it will just return the string.